# Remove special characters with gsub() that are in a certain sequence

Tags: r

I have been trying to clean a df column with R by using gsub function with some success. I am trying to remove `>` and `/` when they are not in between strings containg letters. I got stuck at the following stage:

Input:

```
/ > abcdef/bbb
abcdef/ccc > / > abcdef/ccc > /
abcdef/bbb > abcdef/ccc > / > / > bbb/ccc
```

Desired Output:

```
abcdef/bbb
abcdef/ccc > abcdef/ccc
abcdef/bbb > abcdef/ccc > bbb/ccc
```

I have used `gsub("(/ >)", "", df[,1])` and `gsub("( > /)", "", df[,1])` but does not work. The whitespace makes it more difficult as I want to keep it when the `>` sign is precceding or following strings of letters/words.

Does anyone know a workaround this? I am not really a coder so any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warning: This removes the space: Data from @Maurits Evers 's answer:

```
   library(stringr)
    ss1<-str_remove_all(ss,'[/ >](?<= )')
    str_remove_all(ss1,"(/>)|(>/)")



 #[1] "abcdef/bbb"                    "abcdef/ccc>abcdef/ccc"        
#[3] "abcdef/bbb>abcdef/ccc>bbb/ccc"
```

This preserves it but I find it a bit of trial and error:

```
str_remove_all(ss,"(/ >)|(> /)")

#[1] " abcdef/bbb"                         "abcdef/ccc  > abcdef/ccc "          
#[3] "abcdef/bbb > abcdef/ccc   > bbb/ccc"
```

Comment: Hey Nelson. Thank you for your answer! For some reason after I loaded library(stringr) the function str_remove_all() wasn't found. However I found a similar function to your answer which produced the desired result: str_replace_all(ss, "(/ >)|(> /)", ""). It works well over large datasets and so far it looks very clean. Seems like gsub() isn't that great with special characters. Thanks again for yout answer!

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
gsub("(/ > | > /)", "", ss)
#[1] "abcdef/bbb"                        "abcdef/ccc > abcdef/ccc"
#[3] "abcdef/bbb > abcdef/ccc > bbb/ccc"
```

---

### Sample data

```
ss <- c("/ > abcdef/bbb", "abcdef/ccc > / > abcdef/ccc > /", "abcdef/bbb > abcdef/ccc > / > / > bbb/ccc")
```

Comment: Hey Maurits. In case of a repeating sequence of the same pattern your solution only removes the first occurrence. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Hi @Dragos; unless I misunderstood your question I don't think your assessment is correct. Take a look at the third example; `gsub` removes *both* occurrences of " > / ". That's the whole point of `gsub` (versus `sub`): `gsub` replaces *all* matches, whereas `sub` replaces only the first. This should really just be a simple matter of `gsub`; no need for additional libraries.